# How do I filter directories with powershell on the amount of files contained

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, directory, backup

I am having issues finding the correct syntax I need to filter my results on only listing directories with a file count of above a specified amount (600 in my case).

This is my code so far;

```
$server_dir= "D:\backup"
$export_dir= "C:\support\spcount.txt"

if($server_dir)
{

      $folders = Get-ChildItem $server_dir
        $output = @()

    foreach($folder in $folders)
    {

       $fname = $folder.Name
       $fpath = $folder.FullName
       $fcount = Get-ChildItem $fpath | Measure-Object | Select-Object -Expand Count
       $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{FolderName = $fname; FileCount = $fcount} | Format-List; 
       $output += $obj

    }
     #Output
       $output | Tee-Object -FilePath $export_dir | Format-list FileCount
}
```

And I am getting positive results with this, it is listing all Child Items within the backup dir however I need to filter this to only display and out too text format IF the directory contains 600 or more files.

Can anybody help me please?

I am fairly new too powershell so please pull me up if this code is not the greatest, I am forever wanting too learn.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue. It's that `Format-List` statement at the end of your object creation statement. It pipes the newly created object through `Format-List`, and thus transforms it into something else.

```
$obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{FolderName = $fname; FileCount = $fcount} | Format-List
```

So if you remove that last bit, you'll get the object you expect

```
$obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{FolderName = $fname; FileCount = $fcount}
```

So when you use the `where` statement to filter, you'll actually have a FileCount property to filter on.
I detected it by running the $output through `Get-Member` which showed me it wasn't the object with the expected properties.

So basically, here's your code, including fixes:

```
if($server_dir)
{
    # *** Added the -directory flag, cause we don't need those pesky files ***
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $server_dir -directory
    $output = @()

    foreach($folder in $folders)
    {

       $fname = $folder.Name
       $fpath = $folder.FullName
       $fcount = Get-ChildItem $fpath | Measure-Object | Select-Object -Expand Count
       # *** Format-List was dropped here to avoid losing the objects ***
       $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{FolderName = $fname; FileCount = $fcount}
       $output += $obj

    }

    # *** And now the filter and we're done ***
    $output | where -Property FileCount -ge 600 | Tee-Object -FilePath $export_dir | Format-list FileCount
}
```

Note also the `-directory` to get only folders with `get-childitem`, and the `-ge 600` (**g**reater than or **e**qual) instead of `-gt 599` which is just a bit more obvious.

Remember that the Format-* statements actually transform the data passed through them. So you should only use those at the end of the pipeline to show data on screen or dump it to a file.
Don't use it to transform the data you still want to work with later on.

Comment: You sir, are brilliant. I had a feeling it was the Format-List operator, I hope you can pardon me since I have only been doing this for a few months lol. Thanks n3wjack for this, I really appreciate it and I now know where it is appropriate to use my Format-List operator.

Answer (score 0):

So in short you could do something like this to get that information.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Directory | 
    Select Name,@{Label="Count";Expression={(Get-Childitem $_ -file -Recurse).Count}} | 
    Where-Object{$_.Count -lt 10}
```

Let see if we can incorporate that in your code. Your `if` statement is also kind of pointless. Your variable contains a non-null \ non-zerolength string so it will *always* be True. You want it to work if the directory exists I imagine.

```
$server_dir= "D:\backup"
$export_dir= "C:\support\spcount.txt"

if(Test-Path $server_dir){
    Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Directory | 
        Select Name,@{Label="Count";Expression={(Get-Childitem $_ -file -Recurse).Count}} | 
        Where-Object{$_.Count -lt 10} |
        ConvertTo-Csv | Tee -File $export_dir | ConvertFrom-Csv  
} Else {
    Write-Warning "$server_dir does not exist."
}
```

Just working on getting this to file and screen with `Tee` just a moment.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for your help. It looks like the comparison operators are the key factor here that are stopping me from getting the results.

`Where-Object{$_.Count -lt 10}` is bringing back 0 results, however when I alter this to -ge 600 or -gt 599 I get nothing...

Comment: @KieranGroome My code requires 3.0 which could be a factor. What is your PowerShell Version and do you get results if you remove the line with the `where` clause

Comment: I am testing this on a 2012 R2 server which has currently version 4 of powershell by default. If I disable line 7, the `where` clause, it does return results in a formatted table however the count is `0`, it is as if the `Get-ChildItem.Count` string isn't returning values.

Comment: Curious. Ok I will test with my 2012 server when I get into work

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways to do this.

Filter it in your output like this:

```
$output | where -property FileCount -gt 599 | # ... your code to write to the output
```

Or not store it in the output array if it doesn't match the condition:

```
if ($fcount -gt 599) {
   $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{FolderName = $fname; FileCount = $fcount} | Format-List;
   $output += obj
}
```

Comment: Hey n3wjack, thanks for your help. It looks like the comparison operators are the key factor here that are stopping me from getting the results.

`where -property FileCount -gt 599 |` is bringing back 0 results, as well as:

`if ($fcount -gt 599) {` gives me neither as well.

I think maybe my formatting on:

`$obj= New-Object psobject -Property @{FolderName = $fname; FileCount = $fcount} | Format-List; 
       $output+= $obj`

May be incorrect, as I cannot successfully export to CSV either with this, only plain text and the column headers don't export correctly.

Comment: Could it be that the $fcount isn't a number but an object or a string perhaps? I was assuming it's a number, but if that isn't the case, the -gt will do a different comparison of course. 
You can use `$fcount | get-member` to find out what the type is. It should say `System.Int32` for a number.

Comment: Get-Member results on $fcount show it as `System.Int32` strange